# yii Active Record change model instance if exist

Tags: php, oop, yii

Recently i've met with interesting situation.
I have 2 models: Account(id, username, password) and Post(id, account_id, title, ...)
I created form by the [wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/19/how-to-use-a-single-form-to-collect-data-for-two-or-more-models/). Everything work ok. But my problem is Account->username must be unique)))
So, i decided to add validation rule to the model Account:

```
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        ---
        array('username', 'checkForUnique'),
        ---
    );
}

public function checkForUnique($attribute, $params)
{
    $model = $this->findByAttributes(array("username" => $this->$attribute));
    if ($model) {
        // I do not know what to do
    }
}
```

And my question is:
How to check username and if username already exist, change instance of model Account to the $model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For validation unique value you can add this rule:

```
public function rules()
{
   return array(
      ...
      array('username', 'unique'),
      ...
   );
}
```

You should check model in controller, and if model with same username is already exists than use it, if not - then use new instance:

Your controller:

```
...
    $model = $this->findByAttributes(array("username" => $_POST["Account"]["username"]));
    if(is_null($model)){
        $model = new Account();
    }
...
```

And then fill in the data in $model, validate and save it.

Comment: Thank you, it is a solution to my problem. But is there any way to transfer logic to the model?

Comment: @УрматЖеналиев I did not mention the add errors. You should not change instance, but begin to work with existing record if record with same name already exists or with new record if `username` record with same name is not exists.

Comment: You can implement `getModelByUsername()` method in model which return you new model or existing model found by `username` attribute from $_POST array.

Comment: ."Add error" was the answer to the previous help)))

Comment: Yes, now I understand!